# Nested Futures lead to worse performance

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

I have a set of tasks. Each such task is usually fairly small except for a few which are big. Initially I had one `Future` per Task. This, however, lead to me having to wait quite a bit for the few `Futures` that had a larger task with a lot of CPUs on Idle. I wanted to change this by checking whether a task exceeds a certain size and if so split the task again into multiple `Futures` solving a subtask. This however lead to worse performance as suddenly the first set of futures is executed sequentially. None of the tasks or subtasks are related and, thus, can be solved independently from each other.

Below is the proof of concept for this behavior. Tested in scala 2.13.4.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future, blocking}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.sys.process._

object Main {

       val workSet : List[Int] = List(
           3000,
           3000,
           3000,
           12000,
           3000,
           3000,
           3000,
           12000,
           3000,
           3000,
           3000,
           3000,
           3000,
       )

       def stupidWait(wait : Int) : Int = {
           println(s"waiting for $wait")
           val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
           while ( (start + wait) > System.currentTimeMillis()) {}
           1
       }

       def smartWait(wait : Int) : Int = {
           val work = if(wait > 3000) {
             List(3000,3000,3000,3000)
           } else {
             List(3000)
           }
           println(s"smart working with ${work}")
           val future = Future.sequence {
               work.map {
                  wait => Future { stupidWait(wait) }
               }
           }
           Await.ready(future, Inf)
           1
       }

       def time() : String = {
           "date".!!
       }

       def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
           println(s"${time()} dumb start")
           val futureI = Future.sequence {
               workSet.map {
                   wait => Future { stupidWait(wait) }
               }
           }
           Await.ready(futureI,Inf)
           println(s"${time()} dumb end")
           println(s"${time()} smart start")
           val futureII = Future.sequence {
               workSet.map {
                   wait => Future { smartWait(wait) }
               }
           }
           Await.ready(futureII,Inf)
           println(s"${time()} smart end")
       }

}
```

The output is:

```
Thu Mar  4 08:09:42 PM CET 2021
 dumb start
...
Thu Mar  4 08:09:54 PM CET 2021
 dumb end
Thu Mar  4 08:09:54 PM CET 2021
 smart start
...
Thu Mar  4 08:10:39 PM CET 2021
 smart end
```

I would have expected the smart wait to be at least as fast or even faster, as the larger wait times are now split into 4 potentially parallel wait times. This however is not the case.

**Why is the smartWait not faster and how do I have to change the code make smartWait work as intended?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of threads available to the executor is limited to the number of cores you have by default (it is generally pointless to run more things in parallel than you have cores to execute them).

I figure, you probably have 8 cores. So, the first 8 waits start right away, and the other 5 are queued. Then 3 seconds later 6 threads complete their tasks, and pick up the remaining 5. So, after 3 more seconds everything is done except for the two larger tasks, that keep spinning for another 6 seconds.

Now, what happens with "(apparently not so)smart wait"?

I added number of seconds since the start and thread name to your output to make it easier to track what's going on:

```
    0: scala-execution-context-global-16: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-18: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-21: smart working with List(3000, 3000, 3000, 3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-19: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-17: smart working with List(3000, 3000, 3000, 3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-14: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-20: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-15: smart working with List(3000)
    0: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
    3: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
    3: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
    6: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
    6: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
    9: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
    9: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
   12: 

   12: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
   15: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
   15: scala-execution-context-global-17: smart working with List(3000)
   15: scala-execution-context-global-21: waiting for 3000
   15: scala-execution-context-global-22: waiting for 3000
   18: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
   18: scala-execution-context-global-19: smart working with List(3000)
   18: scala-execution-context-global-16: waiting for 3000
   18: scala-execution-context-global-21: waiting for 3000
   18: scala-execution-context-global-22: smart working with List(3000)
   18: scala-execution-context-global-18: smart working with List(3000)
   21: scala-execution-context-global-17: waiting for 3000
   21: scala-execution-context-global-20: waiting for 3000
   21: scala-execution-context-global-16: smart working with List(3000)
   21: scala-execution-context-global-15: waiting for 3000
   21: scala-execution-context-global-21: waiting for 3000
```

See, how 8 "smart" tasks are started first. They all get blocked, because no threads remain in the pool to execute inner futures.

Then thread #22 is added (the last line with `0` in the first column).

**Note**: There is some pretty clever and involved logic in the `ForkJoinPool` implementation that is used to detect that all threads in the pool are blocked waiting on a condition, and to start an extra one when that happens (the `blocking` mentioned in the other answer is used to aid that. Following that advice will make this test complete in about 3 seconds ... but is fairly useless IRL when you need the actual cores). It does not *always* work, and does not work with all thread pool implementations. If you used some executor other than the default, (or blocked in some different way), chances are, the whole process would just get locked up at this point.

So, it detects the deadlock, and starts thread 22 to resolve it. This new thread picks up one of the submitted futures from the queue and runs it for three seconds. That frees up thread 22 and thread 20, so two more tasks are executed (at 3 second mark). That takes 3 more seconds. It looks like the tasks that got run belonged to one of the larger items, so no additional threads a freed up, we still only have 20 and 22, every thing else is blocked. So they pick another two tasks to run for 3 seconds, and so on.

Note how by the 12 second mark, only 7 tasks have actually run, which is just about 1/3 of the list.

You can keep tracing the output like this to see how things progress.

One fairly universal rule of thumb working with futures is to *never block an active thread*. It is actually pretty dangerous, and could lock up the entire process (as I said above, it's pretty much luck that we don't get it here).

Doing the splitting *outside* of the future, so that you don't have to block waiting for the inner future to return is probably the easiest and safest solution in your situation:

```
    Future.traverse(
       workSet.flatMap { 
          case 3000 => Seq(3000)
          case => Seq.fill(4)(3000)
       }
   ) { n => Future(stupidWait(n)) }
```

Or, to minimize changes to the original code, just make `smartWait` return the future rather than waiting for it, and then in the `main` get rid of the outer `Future` and just do `Future.traverse(workSet)(smartWait)`.
This should complete in about 6 seconds.

Comment: Yes I want to know why the `smartWait` is that much slower as I expected it to be faster. 45 seconds cannot be explained by GC, especially as the cores are idle. Furthermore, the parent `Futures` running the `smartWait` are executed sequentially. This is the actual time sink. Your answer does not address this. Have you ran the PoC?

Comment: @Sim So, the cause of the slowdown (limited thread availability) that I mentioned was correct, but the actual sequence of the events I got wrong. I changed my answer to correct it, hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: Yes, great explanation. Now it makes sense. Though it is quite annoying for me as this basically means that I need to find a workaround for that issue IRL. I wonder whether there is such a thing as `waitOn(future)` that tells the FJP that the current Future can be paused until the referenced future(s) are completed?

Comment: Surrounding the `stupidWait` equivalent in my code with `blocking`  actually solved the issue. However, I do not understand why. But this comment might help future users in trying this solution even though you suggest it might not be as useful IRL.

Comment: @Sim Re. "waitOn(future) that tells the FJP that the current Future can be paused until the referenced future(s) are completed? " –– That's exactly what `Await.ready` (and `blocking` more generally) does (`Await` uses `blocking` under the hood). But like I said, it won't work with all executors, and even with FJP it won't _always_ work well. Moreover, "tricking" the executor into believing you are going to block when you really aren't, will do you more harm than good: excessive number of threads competing for CPU may be even worse IRL than thread starvation.

Comment: The correct solution here is to "flatten" the list of tasks to be run, like I explained in the end of that long answer.

Comment: @Sim re. why `blocking` help you real code: that would depend on what the `stupidWait` thingy is actually doing. If it is _really_ blocking (e.g., IO) for instance, that would make sense,  though, I'd still maintain this is _not_ the "right" solution in that case: allowing the number of threads to grow unbounded is dangerous, and creating a whole lot of "extra" threads with "nesting" is wasteful, and hard to maintain. A better approach would be to (1) still flatten the list to avoid the waste, and (2) use dedicated thread pool with number of threads appropriate for the job.

Comment: @Dima ExecutionContext.global will not grow unbounded, see maxExtraThreads here: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext$.html#global:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor

Comment: @ViktorKlang well ... (1) 256 (in addition to however many cores you already have) sounds pretty much "unbounded to me", provided that they are not _really_ blocked :) and (2) any sort of boundary that has realistic expectation of being actually hit in this context opens up the possibility of deadlock.

Comment: @Dima Since it's configurable you can pretty much set it to what you want. The "correct" way of solving the code above is to split it up into chunks and submitting continuations to the ExecutionContext. That would allow other work to progress as well as avoiding to make any assumptions w.r.t. the ability of the underlying thread pool to accommodate for managed blocking.

Comment: @ViktorKlang yes, you can set it to what your want, but in the end there are only two possibilities: it is either effectively unbounded (the limit never hit) or deadlock-prone.

Comment: @Dima Assuming the tasks have no mutual dependence and will eventually terminate it will not deadlock—it will merely make progress slower.

Comment: In the context of the OP's sample code, it'll certainly deadlock, as soon as the number of "smart" futures reaches the limit.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```scala
       def stupidWait(wait : Int) : Int = blocking {
           println(s"waiting for $wait")
           val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
           while ( (start + wait) > System.currentTimeMillis()) {}
           1
       }
```

Futures are not optimized for maximum possible parallelism (because that generally means worse performance due to context switches and scheduler overhead.), but rather maximum throughput (using fewer threads), and since what you are doing is not meaningful work (you're essentially just converting electrons into heat), you should tell the ExecutionContext that you're semantically blocking, which allows it to create more threads to maintain parallelism.

A better solution, which would also not presume anything about the capabilities of the underlying thread pool would be to divide the time-consuming work into discrete chunks and resubmit them to the ExecutionContext. This would both make it possible to process other work as well as have a minimal impact on the code itself.

Comment: This is a proof of concept. I am doing 'meaningful' work, but the whole problem would've been a bit large to post. How does this blocking work? What part do you have to surround with blocking?

Comment: When running code on an ExecutionContext, it is expected to return control to the ExecutionContext in a timely manner, to allow other logic to make progress (collaborative scheduling)—if you want to run a heavier task, it is appropriate to surround that chunk of code in a "blocking"-block, because to other logic, it will seem like blocking progress for other tasks.

Comment: You can of course also do: import scala.concurrent.{ blocking => timeConsuming } or equivalent if you want your code to be more indicative of what's happening.

Comment: "Blocking" is supposed to mean "not using CPU", not "time consuming" ...

Comment: @Dima Since I created `blocking` and `BlockContext` I'll reserve the right to assign meaning to the definition(s). ;) From a progress PoV there is no difference between a spin-lock, a park(), and a CPU-intensive operation.

Comment: @ViktorKlang the difference is that an intensive operation _must_ consume a specific number of CPU cycles to make progress. Spin-lock does not.

Comment: @Dima A spin-lock definitely has more variability.